# Проблема с отображением таблицы GridView на Xperia e5

Tags: java, android, gridview

Данные таблицы неверно отображаются, помогите, пожалуйста, исправить.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundMainMenu"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Game">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/field"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.GridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="22.5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:numColumns="9"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:background="@mipmap/bg2">

    </GridView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:text="Выбранное значение:"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/backgroundMainMenu"
            android:text="@string/one"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp">

        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/two"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/backgroundMainMenu"
            android:text="@string/two"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp">

        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/three"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/backgroundMainMenu"
            android:text="@string/three"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp">

        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/four"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/backgroundMainMenu"
            android:text="@string/four"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp">

        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/five"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/backgroundMainMenu"
            android:text="@string/five"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp">

        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/six"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/backgroundMainMenu"
            android:text="@string/six"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp">

        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/seven"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/backgroundMainMenu"
            android:text="@string/seven"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp">

        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eight"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/backgroundMainMenu"
            android:text="@string/eight"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp">

        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nine"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/backgroundMainMenu"
            android:text="@string/nine"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp">

        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Проблема в этом:]

Comment: попробуйте padding = 0 в GridView

Comment: Попробовал, к сожалению, ничего не поменялось.

Comment: и убрать android:layout_marginHorizontal

Comment: Получилось) Однако хотелось бы отступы по бокам оставить. Спасибо!

Comment: Возможно ли уменьшить размер шрифта в таблице или размер ячеек?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065344/trying-to-change-the-font-size-in-a-gridview-in-android

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!